# How to fix "cannot initialize a variable of type 'QGraphicsProxyWidget *' with an rvalue of type 'QGraphicsLayoutItem *'"?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicswidget, qgraphicsproxywidget

I want to parse the `QGraphicsGridLayout`, but getting this error. The thing is I was able to add `QGraphicsProxyWidget` as an item but not able to retrieve it. I want to know how to convert a `QGraphicsLayoutItem*` to `QGraphicsProxyWidget*` in this line of `mainwindow.cpp` code `auto *currentWidget = static_cast<QGraphicsProxyWidget*>(layout->itemAt(row, col));`. When using this `static_cast` is returning a `NULL` pointer please help.

**mainwindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsGridLayout>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QPushButton>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    QVector<QString> node_vector = {"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"};

    QGraphicsGridLayout *layout;
    QGraphicsView *view;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;

public slots:
    void builGridlayout ();
    void updateGridlaout ();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QPushButton *updateGridlayout;
    QWidget *menu;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QGraphicsWidget>
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    /* building the gridLayout when creating the QMainWindow */
    builGridlayout();

    menu = new QWidget;
    QHBoxLayout *menuLayout = new QHBoxLayout(menu);
    menu->setLayout(menuLayout);

    /* creating the button to update GridLayout */
    updateGridlayout = new QPushButton("update gridlayout");
    menuLayout->addWidget(updateGridlayout);
    connect(updateGridlayout, &QPushButton::released, this, &MainWindow::updateGridlaout);

    menuLayout->addStretch();
    this->setMenuWidget(menu);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

/* creating a GraphicsGridLayout with QGraphicsProxyWidget */
void MainWindow::builGridlayout()
{
    layout = new QGraphicsGridLayout;
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

    QGraphicsWidget *window = new QGraphicsWidget();

    int numCols = 4,row = 0,col = 0;
    for(int index = 0; index < node_vector.size(); index++){

        QString node = node_vector[index];

        QLabel *label = new QLabel;
        label->setText(node);
        label->setMargin(5);

        /* converting the QLabel into QGraphicsProxyWidget and
         * adding it the QGraphicsGridLayout*/
        QGraphicsProxyWidget *stringLabel = scene->addWidget(label);
        layout->addItem(stringLabel,row+1, col+1);

        col++;
        if(col == numCols) row++;
        col = col % numCols;
    }

    window->setLayout(layout);
    scene->addItem(window);

    view = new QGraphicsView(scene, this);
    setCentralWidget(view);
    view->setGeometry(0, 0, this->maximumWidth(), this->maximumHeight());
    view->show();
}

/* method to update the QGraphicsProxyWidget present in the QGrpahicsGridLayout */
void MainWindow::updateGridlaout()
{
    int itemCount = layout->count();

    int numCols = 4;
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; ++i)
    {
        auto *currentWidget = static_cast<QGraphicsProxyWidget*>(layout->itemAt(row, col));

        if (currentWidget) qDebug() << "successful";
        else qDebug() << "getting nullptr";

        col++;
        if (col == numCols) row++;
        col = col % numCols;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

`QGraphicsProxyWidget` is a [`QGraphicsWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicswidget.html), which in turn is **both** `QGraphicsObject` **and** `QGraphicsLayoutItem`.

[`QGraphicsGridLayout::itemAt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsgridlayout.html#itemAt-1) returns `QGraphicsLayoutItem`, hence by writing this:

```
QGraphicsProxyWidget *currentWidget = layout->itemAt(row, col);
```

the compiler recognizes only the `QGraphicsLayoutItem`-part of this multiple inheritance and gives you an error.

### Solution

Cast `layout->itemAt(row, col)` explicitly to `QGraphicsProxyWidget` like this:

```
auto *currentWidget = static_cast<QGraphicsProxyWidget *>(layout->itemAt(row, col));
```

**Note:** You have to be sure, that the item at this position is indeed `QGraphicsProxyWidget`. If you have some kind of `QGraphicsLayout` instead, your program will crash.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried this `auto *currentWidget = static_cast<QGraphicsProxyWidget *>(layout->itemAt(row, col));`, but the static_cast is returning a null pointer.

Comment: @suryasai Then you have to prepare a proper [mcve].

Comment: I tried to make a `MRE`. I have updated the question. I was able to add `QGraphicsProxyWidget` to the `QGraphicsGridLayout` in `buildGridLayout` function but was not able to update them in `updateGridlaout` function. please help.

Comment: @suryasai, very good! I will take a look later.